# Never-ending loop?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to display 3 submit buttons on a page at random positions. I have managed to do this. I have now created three functions that generate the coordinates for these buttons and also check that they do not overlap too much with other buttons.

Somewhere in these functions I think I am creating an infinite loop - but I can't see why that would be the case...

Here is the code. The functions are defined and called in the header.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            input[type='submit']{
                position: absolute;
                width: 300;
                height: 50;
                color: white;
                background: red;
            }
        </style>
        <?php 

        $first=array(2,4,8,10);
        $second=array(2,4,8,10);

        $b=rand(0,3);
        $c=rand(0,3);

        $f=$first[$b];
        $s=$second[$c];

        $d=$f*$s;
        $score=$_SESSION["score"];
        $name=$_SESSION["name"];

        function firstxy(){

        $x1=rand(0,500);
        $y1=rand(0,500);
        }

        function secondxy(){
            $x2=rand(0,500);
            $y2=rand(0,500);
            if ($x2-$x1<30 ||$x1-$x2<30){
            secondxy();
        }
            if ($y2-$y1<30 ||$y1-$y2<30){
            secondxy();
        }}

        function thirdxy(){
            $x3=rand(0,500);
            $y3=rand(0,500);
            if ($x3-$x2<30 ||$x3-$x1<30||$x2-$x3<30||$x1-$x3<30){
            thirdxy();
        }
            if ($y3-$y2<30 ||$y3-$y1<30||$y2-$y3<30||$y1-$y3<30){
            thirdxy();
        }}

        firstxy();

        secondxy();

        thirdxy();
        ?>
        </head>
    <body>

        <?php

        echo $name." your score so far=".$score;
        echo "<br>";
        ?>

        <?php echo"Write the answer";?>
        <br>
        <?php echo $f."x".$s."=";?>
    <form method= "post" action="submit.php">
        <input type="number" name=a value="0">
        <input type="hidden" name=b value=<?php echo $f;?>>
        <input type="hidden" name=c value=<?php echo $s;?>>
        <input type="submit" name=submit value=<?php echo $d;?>>

        <input type="submit" id="btn" value=<?php echo $d;?>>
    <input type="submit" id="btn2" value=<?php echo " Wrong answer";?>>
    <input type="submit" id="btn3" value=<?php echo " Wrong answer";?>>
    </form>
    <script>
            var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
//btn.style.top = Math.floor((Math.random() * 230) + 1) + "px";
//btn.style.left = Math.floor((Math.random() * 200) + 1) + "px";
btn.style.top = <?php echo $x1;?>+ "px";
btn.style.left = <?php echo $y1;?> + "px";

var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
//btn2.style.top = Math.floor((Math.random() * 230) + 1) + "px";
//btn2.style.left = Math.floor((Math.random() * 200) + 1) + "px";
btn2.style.top = <?php echo $x2;?>+ "px";
btn2.style.left = <?php echo $y2;?> + "px";

var btn3 = document.getElementById("btn3");
//btn3.style.top = Math.floor((Math.random() * 230) + 1) + "px";
//btn3.style.left = Math.floor((Math.random() * 200) + 1) + "px";
btn3.style.top = <?php echo $x3;?>+ "px";
btn3.style.left = <?php echo $y3;?> + "px";
        </script>

</body></html>
```

Comment: In `secondxy` the `$x1` is always going to be undefined. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Same in thirdxy also

Comment: @chris85 So, if I declare the $x1, $y1 etc... initially, outside the functions, then declare them global inside the functions... it should work?

Comment: The values will be accessible in the functions at that point. I'm not sure if it will or won't work as you expect. Turning on error reporting would also be good while debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are checking for overlap, you should use abs(). The following condition will always pass, because one of $x2-$x1 or $x1-$x2 will be negative (therefore less than 30).

```
if ($x2-$x1<30 ||$x1-$x2<30)
```

Try doing something like

```
if (abs($x2-$x1) < 30){
```

Comment: It will always pass because $x1 is always undefined.